# How to create ConfigMap from directory using helm

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress

I have a folder with 3 json files in a `postman` folder. How can I create a ConfigMap using a Helm yaml template?

```
kubectl create configmap test-config --from- 
file=clusterfitusecaseapihelm/data/postman/
```

The above solution works, but I need this as yaml file as I am using Helm.

Comment: Have you run through [Accessing Files Inside Templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#accessing-files-inside-templates) in the Helm documentation?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Inside a Helm template, you can use the `Files.Glob` and `AsConfig` helper functions to achieve this:

```
{{- (.Files.Glob "postman/**.json").AsConfig | nindent 2 }}
```

Or, to give a full example of a Helm template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config
data:
  {{- (.Files.Glob "postman/**.json").AsConfig | nindent 2 }}
```

See [the documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/#configmap-and-secrets-utility-functions) (especially the section on "ConfigMap and secrets utility functions") for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume

Comment: Looks like the folder must also be in the chart directory and not on any other path.

Comment: Updated Link: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/#configmap-and-secrets-utility-functions

Comment: @TinCan updated the link in my anwser. Thanks for the hint.